# clang-format How to disable columned grouping of list

Tags: c++, clang-format

I have an array of pointers, formatted exactly how I want:

```
STTS75 *all[] = {
    &Thermistors::Main::motor,  
    &Thermistors::Main::lower,
    &Thermistors::Heater::upper,
    &Thermistors::Heater::lower,
    &Thermistors::button,
};
```

Which, when formatted with `clang-format`, turns into this:

```
STTS75 *all[] = {
    &Thermistors::Main::motor,   &Thermistors::Main::lower, &Thermistors::Heater::upper,
    &Thermistors::Heater::lower, &Thermistors::button,
};
```

I personally *detest* **1D** lists being presented in **2D** (with columns).
It simply makes it harder to read.

I'm trying to find a `clang-format` option to disable this column grouping but not finding it.

I've looked through all of the alignment options, since it looks like that's doing some work here.
The word "column" occurs too many places in the docs to try them all effectively.

Does the option I'm looking for exist?

I'm well aware I can use `// clang-format off` but I feel like this should not be necessary.

Alternatively, are there other C++ formatters that could do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set these in your `.clang-format`:

```
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
```